# Compare if a JSON contains subset of another JSON in Java

Tags: java, json

How can I compare if a generic JSON is included in another generic json in Java

For Example
JSON 1 :

{
"id": "1",
"name": "Michael Jordan",
"age": "50"
}

JSON 2 :

{
"name": "Michael Jordan"
}

So if JSON 2 contains matches the key and value pair in JSON 1 ignoring the other attributes the program should return true or else false.

Currently Using this Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31858585/19840742

But it's a hit or miss situation working sometimes and sometimes don't as I need to pickup the json values from a excel sheet.

Comment: You forgot to include your attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: Edited to add the solution I'm using right now

Comment: If you canonicalize the json in such a way that all properties are sorted in the same way and numbers are represented in the same way, you could just use string comparison with String.contains(...). I guess you would have to pull of the top and bottom brace from JSON 2, but that is easy.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "working sometimes and sometimes don't"?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `org.json.JSONObject`, then it is super easy.

```
public static boolean isSubset(JSONObject superset, JSONObject subset) {
    return new JSONObject(superset, JSONObject.getNames(subset)).similar(subset);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your objects implement the Map interface, like JsonObject in JSR-374 does, you can use

```
public boolean isSubset(JsonObject superset, JsonObject subset) {
    return superset.entrySet().containsAll(subset.entrySet());
}
```